# render partial in content_for render not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a view I have

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <%= render @render %>
<% end %>
```

@render has value of 'intro'. The partial is not rendered. If I do:

```
<% content_for :header do %>
  <%= render 'intro' %>
<% end %>
```

everything works great. Can someone explane why @render doesn't work?

Comment: How did you verify that `@render == 'intro'` at that place? If it doesn't render, what happens instead? Nothing? An error message?

Comment: cause i did a <%= @render %> in the <body> section and showed me 'intro'. There is no error message. the view is rendered totally except the partial.

Comment: If `<%= @render %>` renders `intro` than this only tells you that `@render.to_s` returns the string `intro`. That does not necessarily mean that `@render` is a string (could be a symbol or a object with an overridden `to_s` method). You might want to check `<%= render.inspect %>` or `<%= render == 'intro' %>`.

Comment: Already tried to_s, no success

Comment: I am sorry if my comment wasn't clear. I didn't want to try `to_s`, because `<%= %>` calls `to_s` internally anyway. I asked you to check the other versions.

Comment: Try `<% @foo = 'intro' %>  <% content_for :header do %>
  <%= render @foo  %>
<% end %>` and see what you get. If it work then your `@render` variable does not contain `string`.

Comment: Doesn't work. Same outcome, partial is not rendered.

Comment: @diedaaf Could you ckeck this please:
`<% foo = 'intro' %> <% content_for :header do %> <%= render foo %> <% end %>` If that works maybe it somehow dependents on content_for closure.

Comment: See the two posts above @DjezzzL

Comment: @diedaaf if you don't see difference: my variable is just local `foo` not instance variable `@foo`. So could you please try?

Comment: @foo or foo, local or instance variable same effect, no rendering. Probably has something to do with 'content_for  :header'

Comment: Solution : It was a typo in application.html.erb. <%= yield :head%>  ===> <%= yield :header%>